# Solution to the Heat Equation: Time-dependent Source, Spherical Coordinates, Insulating Boundary Condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, fourier-transform, eigenfunctions

I am looking to solve the PDE that takes the form of $$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}-Q(t)=D\nabla^2C$$

where $$\nabla^2C = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r^2\frac{\partial C}{\partial r}$$

I have read that eigenfunction expansion is an option for homogeneous boundary conditions. My boundary conditions are the following:

$$C(r=0,t) = A(t)$$ and
$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial r}\Bigr|_{r=\bar{R}}=0$$

where $\bar{R}$ represents the distance from the source where the insulating "wall" exists.

My initial condition is:

$$C(r>0, t=0) = C_b = 0$$

Do any solutions exist for this problem statement?

Comment: Why not include the actual PDE?

Comment: @Gert Updated - see edit. I would go through the whole derivation but it take me FOREVER to type everything out in MathJax

Comment: That PDE is not separable.

Comment: Have look at this: https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~deturck/m241/inhomogeneous.pdf

Comment: @Gert Dangit - how come? I thought the separability assumption was arbitrary - and so long as I could justify that $Q=Q(t)$ then I could solve?

Comment: No, separation only works for $Q=0$. Just apply the separation procedure in my answer and you'll see. And consult the link above, please.

Comment: Also: I don't think you can solve the problem with some generic source $Q(t) \neq 0$.

Comment: @Gert I did apply the procedure but didn't encounter any problems that I found concerning - that's why I was naively confident in my solution

Comment: Helpful resource: http://www.web.pdx.edu/~daescu/mth427_527/notes_weeks6-7.pdf

Comment: Yes, very helpful.

Comment: Unless you're dealing with some sort of scaled equations, your $Q$ has inconsistent units.  From the pde it's the same as $C_t$ whereas from the boundary condition at $r = 0$ it's $C$. ... Ah, looks like you changed it :)

Comment: @Aruralreader yes I had this realization myself but forgot to change it - see edit

Comment: Also helpful: http://wwwarchive.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M412/Notes412_10.pdf

Comment: The solution can be written out via the corresponfding Green's function. But unlike the case of Laplace equation in a ball, thhis Green's function hasn't a closed form.